# One to Many To Many: One user has many store. One store has many products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning ROR. Trying to build this model: one user can have many store each store can have many product. I've been able to create store linking to its owner but I'm stuck at doing the same for product.

store.rb

```rb
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :products, :foreign_key => :store_id
end
```

product.rb

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :store
end
```

products_controller.rb

```rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:product_name, :product_price, :product_description, :product_tag, :sku_code)
    end
end
```

stores_controller.rb

```rb
class StoresController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_store, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /stores
  # GET /stores.json
  def index
    @stores = Store.all
  end

  # GET /stores/1
  # GET /stores/1.json
  def show
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /stores/new
  def new
    @store = Store.new
  end

  # GET /stores/1/edit
  def edit
  end


  # POST /stores
  # POST /stores.json
  def create
    @store = Store.new(store_params)
    @store.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @store.save
        format.html { redirect_to @store, notice: 'Store was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @store }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @store.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /stores/1
  # PATCH/PUT /stores/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @store.update(store_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @store, notice: 'Store was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @store }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @store.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /stores/1
  # DELETE /stores/1.json
  def destroy
    @store.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to stores_url, notice: 'Store was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_store
      @store = Store.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def store_params
      params.require(:store).permit(:store_name, :store_description)
    end
end
```

I expect when creating a product, it will get the store_id immediately. I'm keep getting "store must exist" message

Answer (score 0):

From Rails 5, `belongs_to` requires the association object to be present. If your `product` object does not have a valid `store_id` (`nil` or inexistent store object), that `product` object will not be valid.

You can bypass this by allowing the association to be optional

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :store, optional: true
end
```

Or, you should allow `store_id` as permitted parameter in your `products_controller` and pass it when you create a new product

```
# below code I assume that your store table has a column called 'store_name'

<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :store_id, current_user.stores, :id, :store_name, prompt: 'Please select the store of this product' %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is temporary solution, I will prefer to to explain him how to pass `store_id` in link to `new` action so we can set `@store` and in `form_for` we can pass `f.hidden_field :store_id, @store.id` for create action.

Comment: Yes, I try to pass store_id. How can I do that?
<%= form_with(model: product, local: true) do |form| %>
      <%= form.hidden_field :store_id, @store.id %>
<% end%>

But then I got error: undefined method `id'

Comment: I edited my answer to include the example of how to add `store_id` to your product form